# Single-Page vs Multi-Page and Server-Side vs Client-Side

Tags: web-development, website-design

I am currently researching the benefits and disadvantages of **SPA** (Single-Page Applications) vs **MPA** (Multi-Page Applications).
Having established that **MPA** is more suitable for my project, I proceeded to discuss Server-Side Rendering vs Client-Side Rendering.
But as I was doing that, I noticed that a lot of benefits, arguments, etc. overlap with arguments in SPA vs MPA.
My conclusion was that pure client-side rendering is not possible with an **MPA** and therefore I have to proceed with server-side rendering combined with client-side (to update small pieces of information). Is my conclusion right?

Because I feel like I'm repeating myself when I talk about rendering after talking about **SPA** vs **MPA**. Right now, the concepts of SPA vs MPA and Client-side vs Server-side are blurred into one for me.

Comment: There are several SPA vs MP websites pages on this forum, and they have been closed due to their answers reflecting personal opinions. This question is way too vague and will probably be shut down.

Comment: @Steve I have received an answer on the different Stack website. Although the question may be vague, I believe it is not opinion based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server-side rendering can be crawled, indexed and ranked by Google. See for example this URL: https://serverless-seo.com/

But other bots like Bing, Facebook, Skype, Twitter and so on can't see what's happening on the client's side. If you share an URL, they can't render a thumb or snippet.

So if you want to have a website/app that can easily be crawled, indexed and ranked, go for server-side rendering.

Answer (score 1):

**SPA**

Single page applications are good in a way that the load time less compare to websites. They're more secure.

***Indexebality & Rendering:*** As of today Google and other search engines can't index JavaScript applications like Angular. These applications uses client side rendering but for search engines to index it should be server side indexable. To get indexed and ranked in search engines we need to implement Angular universal (Hybrid rendering).

**MPA- Websites**

These are good in terms of indexability and search engine optimizations. Since Google and other search engines can't index JavaScript applications like Angular. Less loading speed compared to SPA

***Indexablilty & Rendering:*** Easy to index since all search engines understand HTMLand CSS. Server side rendering is done in websites.